# Oracle materialize hint does not work on CLOB?

Tags: oracle, materialize, clob, materialized-views

I have this sample query:

```
WITH sample
AS
(
SELECT /*+ materialize */ sample_pkg.get_clob_text() clob_text
  FROM dual 
)
SELECT *
  FROM sample
```

When I don't have the materialize hint, it returns the CLOB value but returns nothing when I have it on. Is there a way to remedy that? I use materialize since the method (sample_pkg.get_clob_text() on this example) is being used more than once in our query and we need to optimize it since it eats up alot of resource.

Comment: [This](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/lob-changes/) blog post contains some useful comments related to your issue.